# SQL - Can I use a SELECT statement inside a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery

While running the code below, I'm getting the following error:

Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

```
CREATE table #TBL
(
    Name varchar(1028)
)

INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES('John')
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES('Jack')

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN FirstName in (SELECT * FROM #TBL) 
          then 'A' else 'B' end,
    COUNT(id) as Employees
from Database
GROUP BY CASE WHEN FirstName in (SELECT * FROM #TBL) 
          then 'A' else 'B' end
```

The original idea was to create the table in beginning of the query, so the (SELECT * FROM #TBL) could be used on the query itself, instead of defining the names on each GROUP BY.

EDIT:I want to group by the different names. For example, if John is the only name I have in my list, I can just edit the group by clause to be 
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN FirstName = 'John' then 'A' else 'B' end.
But I want to add many more names, and I want to do it once in the query, instead of each time (the query above is only one of many temp table I use in the query)

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: No I dont think so it is possible! You cannot write select inside the Group by clause. BTW:- why you want to do that?

Comment: I want to group by the different names. For example, if John is the only name I have in my list, I can just edit the group by clause to be GROUP BY CASE WHEN FirstName = 'John' then 'A' else 'B' end. But I want to add many more names, and I want to do it once in the query, instead of each time (the query above is only one of many temp table I use in the query).

Answer (score 1):

You can alsways use subquery or common table expression:

```
with cte as (
    select
        id,
        case when FirstName in (select * from #TBL) then 'A' else 'B' end as GR
    from Database
)
select GR, count(id)
from cte
group by GR
```

or

```
select GR, count(id)
from (
    select
        id,
        case when FirstName in (select * from #TBL) then 'A' else 'B' end as GR
    from Database
) as a
group by GR
```

Or, if you have unique names in #TBL table, you just can use join:

```
select
    case when t.Name is not null then 'A' else 'B' end,
    count(d.id)
from Database as d
    left outer join #TBL as t on t.Name = d.FirstName
group by case when t.Name is not null then 'A' else 'B' end
```

But I'd recommend subquery or cte anyway, so you don't have repeated code in your query.
BTW, `Database` is a very wierd name for table.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to try the Join option. But why would subquery or cte won't cause repeated code in the query? Wouldn't I need to insert them each time I would've use Join?

Comment: AND BTW, Database is not really the name of the table, it was only for the example =)